# Could not resolve resource in constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, designer, visual-studio-2019, material-design-in-xaml

After one of the project loads using `MaterialDesign`, problems started in VS19 - namely, the designer loads for a very long time, and after loading it produces the following:

`Failed to resolve resource "MaterialDesignBody1TextBlock".`

And similar with other MD StaticResource in the window.

In the `App.xaml` I added everything correctly:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary
                Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
...
```

When building and running a project, it looks fine, as it should look. However, the problems in the designer do not disappear, and it becomes impossible to work. How to fix it?

Comment: You're not showing us the relevant code. `MaterialDesignBody1TextBlock`

Comment: No, there really is such a style. Looks like this http://prntscr.com/ombeju

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the answer to this question, it is necessary:

- Clear VS cache
- Create an UI in the AnyCPU configuration
- In the project settings, the target platform `AnyCPU` and check on
  "Preferred 32-bit version"
- Use Release configuration to develop UI